Why does pg_dump include "transaction_timeout" if psql doesn't understand it?
I'm running PostgreSQL 15.7 (in Docker) and connecting with psql and pg_dump 17.0 on Ubuntu 22.04.
I have two databases:

db1 contains my app schema
db2 is empty (newly created)

I run pg_dump to dump db1's schema:
pg_dump --schema-only 'postgresql://.../db1' > schema.sql

I then run psql to run the result on db2 so it will end up with the same schema:
psql 'postgresql://.../db2' < schema.sql

And get this error:  ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "transaction_timeout"
Resulting from line 11:
SET transaction_timeout = 0;

Why?  Why is pg_dump dumping a statement that psql or postgres won't recognize?  And how can I disable all these "SET" statements from being included in my SQL file in the first place?
(All I want are the tables, indices, constraints, and views.)

You said yourself that pg_dump is newer than your server.  psql is passing statements directly to the server.

Why is pg_dump adding things to my SQL file that aren't coming from the database, and that wouldn't be understand by the database if sent back?  That seems like a critical flaw.

And is there a way to turn off the addition of "SET" statements altogether?

Just edit the file.

Because you are dumping with the Postgres 17 version of pg_dump and Postgres 17 does have transaction_timeout. I doubt very much it is causing an issue in restoring the dump outside of issuing the error message.  If you don't wan that message then use the Postgres 15 version of pg_dump. I recommend you read the Notes section here pg_dump.

Also, if you are using the PGDG repos for Postgres in the Ubuntu host you can install the postgresql-client-15 package to have the 15 version of pg_dump available there.

I'm running PostgreSQL 15.7 (in Docker) and connecting with psql and pg_dump 17.0 on Ubuntu 22.04. Why use different versions with different functionality? And why do you expect this to work without any issues?

Frank - I'm done with explaining the same thing over and over and over and over.

I believe this question was closed in error. The issue is not caused by a typo; I hope no explanation is required there. Furthermore, the issue describe clearly can be reproduced.  Indeed, the quote of the docs in the OP's own answer clearly indicates in bold how to reproduce the error: Use pg_dump with an older version of postgres.  However, even if the issue of the false close reason is resolved, it is likely the question will be closed again because it seems to be leading to debate, perhaps because it seeks an opinion-based answer and raises a somewhat controversial question of design.

Nevertheless, I think this is a USEFUL question and answer because it raises the simple facts of design and explains clearly why one might receive ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "transaction_timeout" when backing up and restoring to the very same psql database version that was used for the backup.


"Because pg_dump is used to transfer data to newer versions of PostgreSQL, the output of pg_dump can be expected to load into PostgreSQL server versions newer than pg_dump's version. pg_dump can also dump from PostgreSQL servers older than its own version. (Currently, servers back to version 9.2 are supported.) However, pg_dump cannot dump from PostgreSQL servers newer than its own major version; it will refuse to even try, rather than risk making an invalid dump. Also, it is not guaranteed that pg_dump's output can be loaded into a server of an older major version — not even if the dump was taken from a server of that version. Loading a dump file into an older server may require manual editing of the dump file to remove syntax not understood by the older server."

From the Notes section of the pg_dump docs.  (Thanks to @Adrian Klaver for pointing me to it.)
PS - Emphasis mine.
PPS - This seems like bad design to me, which is why I found it so surprising and needed explicit confirmation.

If by bad design you mean it requires that you read the docs then so be it. Otherwise I don't see a problem, major version changes are not guaranteed  to be compatible and if you mix and match version the onus is on you to deal with that. If you want to reduce the errors maintain apples to apples, use the same major version's clients to deal with it. Lastly you still have not indicated whether the error message thrown actually prevented a successful restore.

"mix and match version" - In a client/server situation, this is to be expected - the server version is often out of your control, and it's silly to have a dozen different versions of psql installed locally to use with different projects.  I would design psql to at least give you the option of only outputting statements that would be compatible with the source database.  That doesn't seem like a radical or unreasonable expectation.

And no, the error thrown did not prevent the schema from loading, but that's not relevant to the core point.

It's a lot of complexity to add to psql/pg_dump for something that doesn't affect most people.

The design principle behind pg_dump is that you can dump an old database and load the dump into a later version without friction. That is impossible for a downgrade: imagine you have a constraint defined as UNIQUE NULLS NOT DISTINCT (new in v15). How would you downgrade that? And since it is not possible to downgrade without loss, pg_dump doesn't even try. Downgrading means editing a plain format dump. If removing one SET command is all it takes, count yourself lucky.

This is not an psql issue. psql is the Postgres command line client and only enters this scenario because you restored a plain text dump. The error message came from the server as it was version 15 and did not understand transaction_timeout.  The issue was you tried to restore backwards and while that can be done(as you proved) it is a gamble. While the server version maybe out of your control, it's corresponding tools may not. If you want less drama use the correct tools: "It's a poor craftsman who blames his tools".

Ya'll keep misrepresenting my situation and my arguments.  I'm not trying to "downgrade" or "restore backwords" - I'm trying to export from a DB and then import right back into the same DB.  I think I've explained myself clearly.  I don't understand the confusion, and I'm tired of fighting it.
